# Redmine 5 with Rails 6.1 is no longer rendering a template file from a plugin correctly, it outputs raw html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine-plugins

I am using the `that_attachments_limit` plugin on *Redmine 5*, available from [Github](https://github.com/ThatCompany/that_attachments_limit).

When using *Redmine 4*, this all worked like a charm, but since the upgrade to a newer version of Redmine (and Rails) this is not working anymore.

In the file `plugins/that_attachments_limit/app/views/attachments/_form.html.erb` I have a line with this code:

```
<%= render file: "#{Rails.root}/app/views/attachments/_form.html.erb", locals: locals %>
```

Before the upgrade, this was `including` the `_form.html.erb` from the base application. After the update, it is outputting the plain text content of the file, like:

```
<% attachment_param ||= 'attachments' %>
<% attachment_format_custom_field ||= false %>
...
```

I tried using a `template`, but this is loading the plugin's views in a loop, and not the views from the base application.

```
<%= render template: "attachments/_form.html.erb", locals: locals %>
```

I assume the method used to include the original base system's `_form.html.erb` is just plain wrong, but I would not know how to easily resolve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using the solution provided here: https://www.redmine.org/boards/3/topics/33949 was helpful.

I created a `Gemfile` with content `gem 'render_parent', '~> 0.1.0'` to use this function, and changed the code from:

```
<%= render file: "#{Rails.root}/app/views/attachments/_form.html.erb", locals: locals %>
```

to:

```
<%= render :parent, {:locals => locals} %>
```

Comment: This is probably only a quick fix, it would be nice to know the best solution.